# How to find a spatial distance between each pair of coordinated locations in R

Tags: r

I tried to find the distance between each pair of coordinated locations. Then, I would like to save it as matrix. However, I would like this matrix includes the number of the location.

I wrote my code but it only gives me the distance between two locations.

Here is my try:

```
library(sp)
data("meuse")
SpDist1 <- function(data) {

  dist <- spDists(meuse)
  n <- length(data)
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):n) {
      d <- dist[i,j]
      dd <- (c(i,j,d))
    }

}
  return(dd)
}
```

I have also tried the following code (which calculate the distance between every location with all other locations and return vectors. For example, it calculates the distance between the first location and all other location and return a vector and so on for the other locations. However, the problem here is that there are many redundant measurements.

`res <-lapply(1:n, function(i) spDistsN1(meuse, meuse[i,]))`

**I would like to remove the distance that is larger than 700 m.**

Comment: I don't know what you expected for dd, since you overwrite its value every iteration.

Comment: using `dd <- (c(i,j,d))` in a loop repeatedly overwrites the value of `dd`. Only the last value is returned. It isn't clear what sort of structure you want. A 3-dimensional array where 1 slice is the row indices, 1 slice the column indices,  and a final slice the original matrix? A matrix really doesn't need its indices to be stored with the values. Doing so seems likely to result in a less useful data structure that consumes more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of storing indices with data strikes me as odd, but presumably you have a motivation for doing so. It would help to write a utility function that takes a 2-dimensional matrix and expands it to an array:

```
pad.matrix <- function(A){
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A)
  face1 <- matrix(rep(1:m,n),nrow = m)
  face2 <- t(matrix(rep(1:n,m),nrow = n))
  array(c(face1,face2,A),dim = c(m,n,3))
}
```

Then, the `dd` that you are trying to construct *might* be:

```
library(sp)
data("meuse")
dist <- spDists(meuse)
dd <- pad.matrix(dist)
```

For example, `dd[4,5,] = 4.0000   5.0000 199.9696`, which is basically the same information as `dist[4,5] = 199.9696`

**On Edit**: Here is a way to create an expanded 2-d matrix from your distance matrix:

```
library(sp)
data("meuse")
dist <- spDists(meuse)
d <- expand.grid(1:nrow(dist),1:nrow(dist))
d$dist <- apply(d,1,function(r)dist[r[1],r[2]])
dd <- as.matrix(d)
dimnames(dd) <- NULL
dd <- dd[dd[,1] < dd[,2],]
dd <- dd[order(dd[,1]),]
```

For example:

```
> head(dd)
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]
[1,]    1    2  147.0884
[2,]    1    3  440.7263
[3,]    1    4  889.3523
[4,]    1    5  953.7662
[5,]    1    6 1025.6077
[6,]    1    7  797.5861
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is really appreciated. I would like to have the output as a matrix where the first column is the first location and the second one is the second location and the third column is the distance between them. So, I will have a large matrix of 3 columns and about 4000 rows.

Comment: @Mary I see what you were trying to do now. Does the edit help?

Comment: I have worked with some code based on your help. It works fine but there are some redundant. I tried this: `ddres <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:155, function(i) dd[i,,]))`. Would you like to add it to your answer? All what I need now is deleting the redundant.

Comment: @Mary `dd` as given in the second approach *is* a matrix. If for some reason you don't like the column names, use `dimnames(dd) <- NULL`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Using `do.call` join all the resutl in a matrix. However, there are repeated distance. For example, the location 2 with location 3 is the same as 3 and 2. So, I need to remoe them.

Comment: I will accept the answer as it solved my problem and will add the one line code. Removing the redundant should be another question.

Comment: @Mary I added an edit which addressed the problem of duplicated entries. The final `dd` is a matrix which only has distances for `i`, `j` with `i < j`.